# Text-Align "Left" only for the "values" of First Column

Tags: html, css

I am trying to archive the below,

All the heading should be aligned Center
"The values of 1st Column=Align Left" and 
"All Values of 2nd, 3rd, and 4th Column=Align Center"

how to archive this, when i have auto-incrementing values in my table

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

body > table > tbody > tr > td{
  text-align: center;
}


body > table > tbody > tr > th
{
  text-align: center;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <col width="55%">
  <col width="15%">
<col width="15%">
<col width="15%">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Money</th>
    <th>Cars</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Franky</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter Thomson</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are looking for :first-child - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: @nikhil can you suggest where should i use it ?

Comment: It is difficult to explain in comment. I have added an answer for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for :first-child - http://w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

```
body > table > tbody > tr > td{
  text-align: center;
}


body > table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `:first-child` pseudo element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

body > table > tbody > tr > td{
  text-align: center;
}
body > table > tbody > tr > td:first-child{
  text-align: left;
}


body > table > tbody > tr > th
{
  text-align: center;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <col width="55%">
  <col width="15%">
<col width="15%">
<col width="15%">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Money</th>
    <th>Cars</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Franky</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter Thomson</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like below:

```
th,td{
  text-align: center;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child{
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use:**

```
tbody td
{
  text-align: center;
}
tbody tr td:first-child{text-align:left;}
```

but make sure to have the thead & tbody tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody td
{
  text-align: center;
}
tbody tr td:first-child{text-align:left;}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%">
  <col width="55%">
  <col width="15%">
<col width="15%">
<col width="15%">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Money</th>
    <th>Cars</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>John Franky</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter Thomson</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart of the :first-child with CSS you can make it with pure html:

```
<table>
  <col width="55%" align="left">
  <col width="15%" align="center">
  <col width="15%" align="center">
  <col width="15%" align="center">
```

OR

```
<table>
  <col width="55%" style="text-align:left">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can also try the nth child selector

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <style>
      table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

     body > table > tbody > tr > td{
      text-align: center;
     } 
    body > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1){
      text-align: left;
     }

     body > table > tbody > tr > th
     {
    text-align: center;
     }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<table>
  <col width="55%">
  <col width="15%">
<col width="15%">
<col width="15%">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Money</th>
    <th>Cars</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Franky</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter Thomson</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </body>
  </html>
```

You  change the value of n and change css for that td